# How to configure kubernetes cluster with corporate ldap, for authentication?

Tags: ldap, kubernetes

How to configure kubernetes cluster  with corporate ldap, for authentication?

I'd not found anything official.

Answer (score 2):

[Kismatic](https://github.com/apprenda-kismatic/kubernetes-ldap) is one of the projects that provides a Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) authentication webhook for Kubernetes. For Kismatic Enterprise Toolkit (KET) source code check out [this link](https://github.com/apprenda/kismatic).

Comment: it seems that the kismatic project was abandoned in the time since this answer was posted.
because of this I developed a similar, lightweigth solution (if it's of some value for anyone): https://github.com/gyselroth/kube-ldap

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation as of K8s 1.3, there is no native support for ldap authentication but using keystone can be a way to bridge to an LDAP or AD.

Found this link showing a sample walk through (with Samba):

http://cloudgeekz.com/1128/how-to-setup-active-directory-or-ldap-authentication-for-kubernetes.html

This implies the API server does the authn for the client... a more flexible solution using keystone tokens might soon be implemented here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/25391